# Why 'no function clause matching' even though four parameters are passed to a function of arity of 4?

Tags: erlang

This is my code in question:

```
-module(test).
-export([seed_matrix2/0, take_row_and_column/4]).


seed_matrix2() ->
    [0, 0, 1, 0,
     4, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 2,
     0, 4, 0, 0].

take_row_and_column(R, C, AnsMatrix, SideLen) ->
    RowVector = [ V || X <- lists:seq(0, SideLen-1), V <- lists:nth(R*SideLen+X, AnsMatrix) ],
    ColVector = [ V || X <- lists:seq(0, SideLen-1), V <- lists:nth(X*SideLen+C, AnsMatrix) ],
    {RowVector, ColVector}.
```

This is the error message I call the function `test:take_row_and_column`:

```
74> test:take_row_and_column(1, 2, test:seed_matrix2(), 4).
** exception error: no function clause matching 
                    test:'-take_row_and_column/4-lc$^1/1-1-'(0) (/private/tmp/test.erl, line 12)
     in function  test:take_row_and_column/4 (/private/tmp/test.erl, line 12)
```

I usually get this when I am passing incorrect number of parameters or fail to satisfy the type guards. I do not understand why this code will trigger a `no function clause matching`

Here is the version banner of `erl`:

```
Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V5.10.4  (abort with ^G)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fix:

```
take_row_and_column(R, C, AnsMatrix, SideLen) ->
    RowVector = [ lists:nth((R-1)*SideLen+X, AnsMatrix) || X <- lists:seq(1, SideLen-1) ],
    ColVector = [ lists:nth((X-1)*SideLen+C, AnsMatrix) || X <- lists:seq(1, SideLen-1) ],
    {RowVector, ColVector}.
```

There were two problems with the code in question:

1) `lists:seq(0, ...)` should be `lists:seq(1, ...)` instead. `lists:nth()` does not like value zero

2)  `erlang` does not like  the `V<-...` part. Need to move the whole `lists:nth()` call to the left of `||`

Comment: If your seed matrix was of a list of lists which is the more obvious representation,  the code would be much simpler.

Answer (score 4):

The failing function in question is the compiler generated function for the list comprehension (note the "-lc$..." in the name). It looks like this is because your generator V <- lists:nth(..., Matrix) tries to pick a number V from a non-list, since lists:nth/2 will return the nth integer from the list. Writing the generator like V <- [lists:nth(...)] should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although the suggested solution does not fix the issue, you answer helps me to understand the error message!